# opencv python transfer ((uchar*)(img->imageData img->widthStep*i))[j];

Tags: c++, python, opencv, iplimage

I tried to transfer opencv c++ code to python.
but i got no idea how to change this line below:

((uchar*)(img->imageData + img->widthStep*i))[j];

when i write it like this:
(img.imageData + img.widthStep * i)[j]

it occurs this Error message:
'cv2.cv.iplimage' object has no attribute 'imageData'

Comment: That's some pretty poorly formed c++.

Comment: -1 for having the cv2 api(which uses numpy arrays for anything), but using the old(1.0) one instead (cv2.cv.iplimage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple.

`img[i, j]` will give you a tuple of `(B, G, R)` at pixel `i, j.`

Comment: thanks. I(x,y) ~ ((uchar*)(img->imageData + img->widthStep*y))[x]. Also Can see FAQ here http://www.opencv.org.cn/index.php/FAQ%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87